# Magento->filter product visibility in collection

Tags: magento-1.4

We use this Magento code to get a list of publications to pick 2 from to show in a Bookstore section.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->joinUrlRewrite()
    ->load();
```

How can I add an attribute to select to make it not include the publications that are set 
to "Not show individually"?

If I add this:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) // Only catalog, search visiblity
```

The code fails with message 'Invalid attribute name: visiblity'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visibility is a product attribute, not a category attribute. To get *products* that only have a visibility of 4, you need to get a product collection and traverse over it to get a definitive list of categories:

```
$categories = array();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
foreach($products as $product){ 
  foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $cat){
     $categories[] = $cat;
  }
}

$categories = array_values(array_unique($categories));
```

Now, with the `$categories` array populated with our unique list of categories, we can load only those categories:

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addIdFilter($categories);
```

Comment: The nice thing about the `addIdFilter` on the category collection is that you can pass it an array of id's, a string of comma-separated id's, or even a singular id itself. It's really useful and flexible.

Comment: How would I filter the products that I already have in the collection from the category?

Comment: Don't re-run my collection that sets $products, rather, just add another criteria. Collections are really flexible - you can do `$collection->getFirst();` and then `$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array('id'=>3));` and it just works. Experiment a bit. The above code is tested and works well.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.

Comment: Have you tried my above code? It works perfectly. You can re-filter any collection by calling `addAttributeToFilter()` on it. Replace line 2 above with your collection var and add the attribute filter.

Comment: Actually, you led me to the correct answer. I added the filter the the products collection which is actually selected later on in the script. I looked a little closer to it and found it.  Thanks.

Comment: Better use the constant and not hard coded integers. For example: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH`

Comment: I agree. Aimed for brevity here and should not have. Good call. @Dor

Comment: Even better, check out `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility`. `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);`.